# Wrap-Panel reording items using drag and drops

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, drag-and-drop, wrappanel

I need to change position of items in WrapPanel (or stack-panel with horizontal orientation) using dragging when user touches with it.

I tried MouseDragElementBehavior, but it changes position for current item only and do not for others.

I saw [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2011/01/03/wp7-reorderlistbox-improvements-rearrange-animations-and-more.aspx) but it working with listBox with vertical orientation. So does exist any ways for this?

Answer (score 0):

A WrapPanel is not the perfect panel for Drag&Drop because it does not have the notion of order. In fact, items are ordered based upon the order in the datasource.

With your example , you can simply change change the ItemsPanel  like this :

```
 <rlb:ReorderListBox

          ...
            <rlb:ReorderListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemWidth="100" ItemHeight="50"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </rlb:ReorderListBox.ItemsPanel>
...
```

Comment: I can't use it. Because ReaderListBox is designed for ListBox (animations, handling of items, etc.)